# Posting json through ajax to mail

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, email, post

here is my code. This works perfect. but i am confused how to post this form to php mail function.
**Ajax**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };

    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

kindly help me..... i will be thankfull to you

help me with the code  The form is here [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9af880t/)

Comment: One of these: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Comment: i tried this. but still fail.. :/

      $('#submit_btn').click(form_registration);
        function form_registration () {

            var input_data = $('#contact_form').serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'php.php',
                data: input_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( msg ){
                    alert('SUCCESS!');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('ERROR!');
                    alert(input_data);
        }
            }); return false };